# Replacing values of a diagonal matrix with specific values in R

Tags: r, matrix, replace, diagonal

I'm new to programming and coding as a whole and am currently learning R here at school as part of my statistics certification.

We have been asked to create a 10 x 10 matrix called ‘mat’ that contains the numbers 1 on the diagonal and 0 on the off-diagonal.

I have done this using the following:

```
mat<-diag(10)
mat
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
   [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
   [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
   [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
   [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
   [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
   [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
   [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
   [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
   [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
  [10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
```

then I am asked to partition off a k x k block of the matrix where k=3 and also has this identity structure and describe how many ways are there to do this.

I only figured out how to do this doing the following:

```
 mat2<-mat[c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3)]
 mat2
          [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    0    0
    [2,]    0    1    0
    [3,]    0    0    1
```

So far so good I guess? However, now I'm really stuck, I have no idea how to go about the following, with mat2 I am now asked to replace the block diagonal portion of mat (mat2) with a matrix like this:

```
          [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1   .5   .25
    [2,]   .5    1    .5
    [3,]  .25   .5     1
```

My professor has also hinted, that using the outer function will make this easier, I really have no idea how I can do this, I tried using upper.tri and lower.tri functions, but I wasn't too successful with that either.

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Re "how many ways?" another way is, eg, `mat[2:4, 2:4]`. Re "replace" maybe look at related docs, `help.search("replace", package="base")`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the replacement matrix ready:

```
mat<-diag(10)
replacement <- matrix(c(1,.5,.25,.5,1,.5,.25,.5,1), nrow=3, byrow=T)
mat[c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3)] <- replacement
```

the put it in for loop to make across the whole diagonal

```
for(idx in 1:8){
    mat[c(idx,idx+1,idx+2),c(idx,idx+1,idx+2)] <- replacement
}
mat
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,] 1.00 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.00
 [2,] 0.50 1.00 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.00
 [3,] 0.25 0.50 1.00 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.00
 [4,] 0.00 0.25 0.50 1.00 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.00
 [5,] 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50 1.00 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.00  0.00
 [6,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50 1.00 0.50 0.25 0.00  0.00
 [7,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50 1.00 0.50 0.25  0.00
 [8,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50 1.00 0.50  0.25
 [9,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50 1.00  0.50
[10,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50  1.00
```